# "Other side" of a ForeignKey relation

Tags: django

I read many times [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial03/) tutorials, but I cant understand, how to do the following:

models:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    field1
    field2
    field3

class CarOptions(models.Model):
    car = models.OneToOneField(Car, primary_key=True)
    field4
    field5

class CarPictures(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    field6
    field7
```

So, I need get all information about the car in one sql-query. How it wrote in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-get-object-or-404):

```
car = get_object_or_404(Car, pk=car_id)
```

But [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial03/#use-the-template-system) is a strange (it discribes like "other side" of a ForeignKey relation) `poll.choice_set.all`, that doesnt works with my code. Some copy-past code, sorry, there is no links in docs:

```
# Give the Poll a couple of Choices. The create call constructs a new
# choice object, does the INSERT statement, adds the choice to the set
# of available choices and returns the new Choice object. Django creates
# a set to hold the "other side" of a ForeignKey relation
# (e.g. a poll's choices) which can be accessed via the API.
>>> p = Poll.objects.get(pk=1)

# Display any choices from the related object set -- none so far.
>>> p.choice_set.all()
[]

# Create three choices.
>>> p.choice_set.create(choice='Not much', votes=0)
<Choice: Not much>
>>> p.choice_set.create(choice='The sky', votes=0)
<Choice: The sky>
>>> c = p.choice_set.create(choice='Just hacking again', votes=0)

# Choice objects have API access to their related Poll objects.
>>> c.poll
<Poll: What's up?>

# And vice versa: Poll objects get access to Choice objects.
>>> p.choice_set.all()
[<Choice: Not much>, <Choice: The sky>, <Choice: Just hacking again>]
```

I havent got `choice_set.all()`. I add all information from the admin interface. With foreign keys all works well, but I need do a few sql-querys, not one. And in the docs they discribed it, like a one sql-query, but they have `choice_set.all()`. How its possible to do with my model? I need all information in the template (html), can you give me some example, how it works? 
Thanks.

Comment: Show what did you try

Comment: Note that this isn't one SQL query unless you specify the related models to select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related managers' names are automatically generated from model names. You have `car.carpictures_set` and `car.caroptions` (this isn't a "set" because it's a one-to-one relationship).

You can define your own related names:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    ...

class CarOptions(models.Model):
    car = models.OneToOneField(Car, primary_key=True, related_name='options')

class CarPictures(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='pictures')
```

Then you'll have `car.options` and `car.pictures`.

[Related objects reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/relations/)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is your view

```
 cars = Car.objects.filter()
 car_options = CarOptions.objects.filter()
 car_pictures = CarPictures.objects.filter()
```

Here how it relates in html

```
{% for car in cars %}
    {% for option in car.car_options %}

    {% endfor %}

    {% for picture in car.car_pictures %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```